# how to detect touch on a android device screen

Tags: android, dialog, touch

In the Activity I rewrite the dispatchTouchEvent method, I can detect the touch event, but open the dialog,and touch the dialog,the activity can not detect the touch event, I would like to touch the dialog, can also get touch event in the Activity,not doing someting in the dialog.

Comment: how will you get a touch in your activity when a dialog is showing?

Comment: i have an idea,detect the screen is being touched,but i don't know how to detect this

Comment: When a dialog is showing you can't get the touch in activity. You need to close the dialog for getting the touch in the activity, else you need to bypass the dialog with some custom view.

Comment: you'll have to override `dispatchTouchEvent` for whatever you want to get touches in (actvity, dialog, etc.)